# How to read the rar file comment on linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, rar, winrar

I have *foo.rar*, and I want to read the file comment

Comment example on Windows: [image]

How to do it in Linux command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
rar v archive.rar fname | grep Comment:
```

should work for a one-liner comment. If the comment spans multiple lines you will need more sophisticated output parsing.

Comment: You can also use the -z parameter http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/rar.1.html

Comment: That -z parameter is actually for setting an archive comment, not reading it.