# How to read rar file comment in java?

Tags: java, file, zip, archive, rar

I have a directory containing both Zip & Rar archives.
I already have a way to get a zip file's comment -

```
if (f.getName().substring(f.getName().length() - 3).equals("zip")) {
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(f);
    zip.getComment();
}
```

Is there a way to do the same thing on a Rar file?

note that:

- There are too many rar files for me to manually convert them to zip on some site (If there is some script to convert them, it could work).
- Renaming a rar file's extension to .zip (file.rar -> file.zip) would still produce an exception when trying to create a new ZipFile object with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I appreciate the comeback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the end, you are looking for some sort of library to get that done for you. Like [raroscope](https://github.com/radarsh/raroscope) or [java-unrar](https://github.com/jukka/java-unrar).

Alternatively, you could decide to re-invent that wheel yourself (not recommended).

Or you simply run the command line rar tool using ProcessBuilder (as a system command), like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943812/how-to-read-the-rar-file-comment-on-linux-command-line).

Comment: Is there an easy way to run the Linux terminal system command inside the java code? I mean I couldn’t think of a way to check all the files and unrar/unzip them accordingly inside the terminal... Anyway, how does one use a public library like raroscope in java? It’s surely more than just an import, right?